# Power BI and Power Automate Flow

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I am using Power Automate flow to create an auto refresh button in Power BI service.

Does the end user who is viewing the data and refreshing the data with the button I created need a license in power automate or a pro license for BI to operate the report since a flow is added to the underlying report?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience the flow will uses you account to do the automation.  what i think you'll have to worry about is the how the person will access the report (pro license or if your have and Premium Workspace) then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need powerbi premium workspace for that user to be able to operate the report mainly because you need to give the person a direct access to the cloud report.